# List of LaTeX3 functions

Tags: latex3

I'd like to have an overall impression of all LaTeX3 could do, but the tutorials I've read all gave only a few functions as examples. Is there anything for LaTeX3 that works like [macros2e](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/macros2e/macros2e.pdf), which is a big list of macros with brief explanation?

Comment: interface3.pdf is the reference

Comment: Here is a link to [`interface3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). The CTAN page of `l3kernel` has some additional interesting resources: https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. Those two seemed quite helpful. Before I was simply looking at the documentation of package ```expl3``` and found limited information.